# ProgessDialog is not shown immediately after clicking on a TextView

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using the following code to show progress dialog on clicking on a TextView:

```
 contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupChatActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Contacts...");
            dialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacts Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhone = getContactsFromPhone();
            Intent intent = new Intent(GroupChatActivity.this, PhoneBookActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
            intent.putExtra("GroupRoomID", roomID);
            Log.e("rID", roomID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

ProgressDialog is dismissed when the activity is destroyed.

```
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

But on clicking contacts ,Progress dialog is not shown immediately ,it is taking too much time .Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. Initialze the dialog outside the Listener

```
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupChatActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Contacts...");
        ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhone = getContactsFromPhone();

    contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacts Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        popupWindow.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(GroupChatActivity.this, PhoneBookActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
        intent.putExtra("GroupRoomID", roomID);
        Log.e("rID", roomID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is working now but creates a new problem.As i am calling getContactsFromPhone() method in onCreate() method,the respective activity is taking too much time .So i guess this is not the perfect solution.